# Problems with staggered image and paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I double click the card the dialog pops up, and it is then possible to create dynamic checkBoxes. So far so good. 
When creating the checkBoxes it is possible to edit or delete the checkBoxes. The problem is that the 'delete image' and 'edit paragraph' don't get placed in a straight vertical line. Instead they get placed in a staggered  way by moving towards the left side. 
You can see the problem in the image below.

[image]

How to avoid this ?

JQuery:

```
function addCheckbox(name, status) {
        status = status || false;

        var container = $('#divboxs');
        var inputs = container.find('input');
        var id = inputs.length + 1;
        var data = {
            status: status,
            name: name
        };

        var div = $('<div />', { class: 'allcheckbox' });
        $('<input />', {
            type: 'checkbox',
            id: 'cb' + id,
            value: name
        }).prop('checked', status).on('change', function () {
            data.status = $(this).prop('checked');
            data.name = $(this).val();
        }).appendTo(div); /* set checkbox status and monitor changes */

        $('<label />', {
            'for': 'cb' + id,
            text: name
        }).appendTo(div);

        var $trashImage = $('<img />', {
            "src": "http://www.seniorclassaward.com/systemadmin/extensions/fieldtypes/ngen_file_field/images/trash-icon.gif",
            "class": "removeCheckBoxDialog",
            "for": "cb" + id
        }).appendTo(div);

        var $editCheckBox = $('<p />', {
            class: 'editCheckBox',
            text: 'Edit'
        }).appendTo(div);

        div.appendTo(container);

        container.data('checkboxes').push(data);
    }
```

CSS:

```
.removeCheckBoxDialog, .editCheckBox {
    margin-top:3px;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
}
.editCheckBox {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: GrayText;
    font-size: small;
    margin-right:8px;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/134/)

Comment: try applying `float:right` for the edit and delete options. The question lacks sufficient info to diagnose the problem. Sharing the relevant HTML or a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net) would help the community to provide a better solution...

Comment: looks like your edit is flowing out of the container div and causing the others to stack.  try adding `clear:right` to your .sortable-div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The margin on your div tripping them.

```
.editCheckBox {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

this works fine on my browser.
You can also use padding and margin with `box-sizing:border-box;`